# What will happen to setIntervals after new document loads in the same session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Will the interval that were set by previous javascript code still persists ?

Comment: A document load is no different to opening a new page, IOW: the interval is no more.

Answer (score 0):

No, when the document is reloaded all JavaScript state is reset. E.g. setInterval, setTimeout, etc will all disappear.

Was there a specific use-case you were after?